# WPF Best Practices: Do custom controls work well with the MVVM design?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, custom-controls

I was looking at creating a common control that I will be able to reuse on my pages: an AddressControl which has Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, etc...

Originally I just created a class (`AddressEntity`) that contained all these items and implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I included that class as a DependencyProperty in my Code-Behind for the AddressControl and used it as the DataContext for the bindings to its properties.

Then, someone said my code was ugly and I should look into MVVM. Looking at it, I assume that:

- AddressEntity.cs will just be a container of data (i.e. Address1, Address2, etc.) and members (i.e. Clone, ToString, etc.)
- I need some AddressViewModel to wrap my AddressEntity in and provide the PropertyNotification Changes, Validation, etc.
- I need to somehow have a "View" for this.

The problem is every example I've ever seen has a UserControl as the View and not a CustomControl. Before I delve too deep into this...

- Is it possible to use MVVM + Custom Controls for this example?
- Is it pretty much the same thing (UserControl vs CustomControl) as the View with the exception of primary differences of UserControl vs CustomControl? Basically, is my CustomControl really just a View?

References: [The Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) Design Pattern for WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090006)

Comment: The two answers below seem to be contrary to each other. I'm confused now... especially since the second answer sounds more likely, but the first answer has (so far 3 votes).

Comment: I would agree with NVM. I have also personally felt that Custom Controls and MVVM can't go well together. You do have CC and UC in same project but I can't think of having a VM for my CCwhereas having VM for UC makes sense.

Comment: @akjoshi I don't see why pure WPF and MVVM has anything to do with each other. In fact no matter if custom or user control you don't need to use MVVM and i would even say you must not use MVVM when creating a user or custom control. BUT using these controls then yes, MVVM is a nice way of using them. I think its easy to distinguish between "Now i make business logik and use MVVM" and "Now i create a control and never heard about mvvm". For example, we built a complete graph control with nodes connection etc. which are all custom controls, but using this control is mostly done via viewmodels.

Comment: @dowhilefor Yes thats always there, using MVVM is not necessary. You yourself provided hint of why MVVM doesn't suit for CC's - 'Buisness logic'; genrally CC's don't have any buisness logic just the implementation and template for the control, CC's are supposed to be usable across multiple applications(like your chart control). It definitely makes sense for the client application to use MVVM *with* CC's but not for *creating* the CC's.

Comment: @akjoshi ok, than we are on the same page and i just missunderstood you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

CustomControls are never done with mvvm.

What you want is a reusable view(user control) of your data and not a control(custom control).

UserControls and CustomControls are two completely different beasts.

EDIT:

Notwithstanding why UserControls were originally developed, in MVVM typically you use a UserControl when you want a reuseable view which is specific to your model/viewmodel. Its just XAMl without any code behind (except for the auto generated InitializeComponent stuff). Generally you keep a UserControl in the same project that you use it in.

You go for a CustomControl when you want a generic piece of functionality which requires a view *and* which has potential use even outside the scope of your current application. Here the control is actually defined in a code file and the look (which can be overriden) comes via XAML in a resource dictionary. 
Generally you keep a CustomControl in a a seperate ControlLibrary project and reference the library in the project you wish to use it in.

With due respect to WallStreetProgrammer, choosing between a user control and a custom control based solely on whether or not you want a lookless control is a bit naive.

Comment: Unfortunately there are a couple of additional concerns when it comes to User vs Custom Controls. For example, the handling of ResourceDictionaries, if done wrong, can render Usercontrols pretty much useless. But i agree, the selection of User or Custom control should not soley be done by the lack of styling.

Comment: If resource dictionaries are not handled correctly you could even render the whole application useless :p. But what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: Of course you are right, but using a MergedDictionary in a user control xaml is much worse, than using a MergedDictionary on your xaml where your style is  stored for your custom control (or your generic.xaml). I learned that leason the hard way. To be honest, i don't see any point of using user controls at all, but thats just my personal opionion.

Comment: "Generally you keep a CustomControl in a a seperate ControlLibrary project and reference the library in the project you wish to use it in"...This statement is not quite accurate because if you try to create a WpfControlLibrary in Blend, it will create a UserControl by default.

Comment: So... it's good to use MVVM with UserControl and it's not with custom control?

Answer (score 3):

When using MVVM the Model and ViewModel should not be dependent on the View, that is they should not care what kind of view use them.

The difference between a custom control and a usercontrol in WPF is that the custom control is lookless and can be customized via its ControlTemplate. This is what you should write if you are writing a generic control library, like Microsoft does. If you however have a specific look in mind for you control, just go with a user control, it is much faster but will only have one look, the one you define for it.

It is common to use a mix of custom controls and user controls in a MVVM project. For example you would probably use a bunch of custom controls from Microsoft (like textboxes and textblocks) and combine them into user controls.

See [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx)