# Manually redrawing a custom control when WPF requests an arrangement

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have a custom control that has a refresh method, something similar to this:

```
public class MyControl : Canvas
{
    // Dependency property for "data" used to draw the control here

    public void Refresh()
    {
        Children.Clear();

        // Using data, draw the control
        Children.Add(new Line(...));
        Children.Add(new Rectangle(...));
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Right now, I have to call `Refresh()` manually each time I want the look of the control to update. My dependency properties are set up for `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange`, so WPF knows that modifying the properties will affect the arrangement of the control and that it should be redrawn. So here's the question:

What does WPF use to tell a custom control that it should be redrawn? Is it an event, or an override, and how should it be used? I've tried handling various events and overrides and nothing seems to work. So, what's the correct way to do this? I want to replace / wrap the `Refresh()` method above in something "automatic" that WPF will handle automatically.

Comment: XY Problem. You're mashing together UI and data. Your approach is too winforms-like. WPF does not support developers with a winforms mentality. What you're looking for is not a "Custom Control", but a simple ViewModel and DataBinding.

Comment: I don't think "simple ViewModel and DataBinding" would work here (yes I am familiar with the MVVM pattern), there is not a 1:1 relationship between the data and the children controls being drawn, there are a lot of calculations, children-of-children, and various options for styles and colors and sizes that are not shown here. It's not nearly as simple as the code sample I provided.

Comment: that's precisely what a ViewModel is for, to act as an itermediary between UI and Data. If you have N "Views" (children UI elements) per data item, simply create N ViewModels. That will move your logic off the UI into a technology-agnostic layer, making things much simpler.

Comment: It's not always "N" though, sometimes it's 2N or n² or ½N. I'm also dealing directly with WPF framework elements like `Ellipse`, `Line`, and `Rectangle`, and tightly coupling your UI with your ViewModel by referencing UI assemblies breaks the entire pattern/purpose of using MVVM. Please stop suggesting I use MVVM, it is not suited to solve this problem.

Comment: `Ellipse`, `Line` and `Rectangle` should be in your DataTemplates. MVVM is suitable for this, you just don't understand it. I made an MVVM diagram designer with all sorts of elements and connectors and drawings, so you can't tell me "it's not suitable"

Comment: Not to mention, the first line in my question states "*I have a custom control*", and it is a custom control in the true sense that it needs to be redistributable, and custom controls are not suited to the MVVM pattern at all (see this answer, which backs up that claim: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3497416/334053). So again, **it's not suited to solve this problem.**

Comment: @qJake this is similar to something I struggle with. Did you find a good solution in the end?