# CustomControl in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am building a complex UI application and one of the windows contains a control that's a Canvas that draws a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of nodes. Because that window was fairly complex (and because I don't know anything about WPF in the first place), I thought I would use a CustomControl (and not a user control, since I thought user control were used to group things together). The application I am trying to build should be following MVVM.

Now I am creating that `GraphControl` as a subclass of the `Selector` control.

Question #1: Is that class the ViewModel? I don't understand the role of the `GraphControl` class in the grand MVVM story.

Question #2: When I add it to my main application, I have to do something like:

```
<GraphControl DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ...
```

which looks to me like I really haven't understood how that stuff is supposed to work.

Help?

**Edit:** Apparently that person had the same problem as I had (https://mutelight.org/datacontext-in-a-custom-control). The solution given in the article is to do this:

```
<GraphControl><Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ...
```

That sounds just as hackish to me though...

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad to be appropriate. Providing a solution for such a fairly complex scenario while the answerer should also explain the basics of MVVM is I think asking for too much. You should start by understanding the principles and the idea behind MVVM by creating hello-world like apps, binding textboxes to viewmodel properties and get a sense of it. Because MVVM is heavily reliant on framework-provided mechanisms I think it doesn't make sense at all to give a sample what you couldn't fully understand or oversee.

Comment: But to provide you with one hint, the example you've provided about `DataContext` is not correct. `DataContext` is not really the item that you would want to use for one certain purpose (such as retrieving the nodes) but rather the binging root of the control for which you specify it. So, if your VM contains deeply nested objects then you can specify it and any controls embedded into it will resolve their bindings relative to that.

Comment: So you would need to write something like this:

`<GraphControl NodeSource="{Binding Nodes}" ... />`

where `Nodes` is a property inside the binding context that wraps this control.

Comment: @Balázs: fair enough. The problem I am having is that regarding WPF and MVVM, there are too many contradicting documentation. For instance, take a look at this question and its answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497219/wpf-best-practices-do-custom-controls-work-well-with-the-mvvm-design

Comment: @Balázs: Aaaah, I think I may be having an epiphany thanks to your last comment. Maybe.

Comment: I agree with that, I know it all too well from personal experience. But while MVVM is pretty complex to understand as a newcomer, once you get the idea it is very pleasant to use. That's why I said start with simple things, so that you can get a sense of how and why all the background "magic" works. Once you've understood that, you can just rely on common sense and personal preferences.

Comment: I think I'm going to ditch the idea of making a `CustomControl` altogether, I think it just doesn't fit my problem.

Comment: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` what's your address?  I'm going to come over to your place and beat the silly out of you.

Comment: Create your custom control, expose DependencyProperties for the explicit values you need to create the graph, use TemplateBindings in your control template to bind to your custom control, and use the codebehind to handle your UI logic.  Then you can use and bind to that control just like any other.  Tada!  You're now an MVVM developer with some sweet UI experience.

Comment: @Will: I'll give you my address if you give me the address of whoever invented XAML.

Comment: @d--b ***NOW ITS ON!!!***

Answer (score 2):

> Question #1: Is that class the ViewModel? I don't understand the role of the GraphControl class in the grand MVVM story.

No. The `GraphControl` is just another control that belongs to the view. Examples of built-in controls include the `TextBox`, the `Button` and the `ListBox` among several others. Your `GraphControl` is just another type of control.

The view model is what the control binds to. Please refer to MSDN for a basic introduction to the MVVM design pattern and the roles of each of the components: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx.

> Question #2: When I add it to my main application, I have to do something like:

You can set the `DataContext` of a control one way or another. The most common approach is to set the `DataContext` of the parent window to an instance of a view model, e.g.:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

A child element inherits the `DataContext` of its parent element in the element tree unless the `DataContext` property is explicitly set to something else.

This means that your control will inherit the `DataContext` of its parent panel which will in turn inherit the `DataContext` from its parent element and so on.

The following sets the `DataContext` of the control to itself which means that you can bind to any properties of the `GraphControl` class without specifying an explicit source:

```
<GraphControl DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ...>
```

Whether you want to do this depends on your requirements.

Comment: `Whether you want to do this depends on your requirements.` Requirements usually don't include "break how databinding works`.  It's a terrible practice and you should be ashamed for hinting it's anywhere near acceptable.  Shame!  Anyhow, it's a custom control, so most likely he'd be using a control template, which means he can use TemplateBindings to bind to properties of the control.

Comment: Are you really saying that is a "shame" to *ever* bind the DataContext property to the element itself?

Comment: @Will misusing the data context in this way is generally a bad idea unless you have a very pressing need, but nothing has been broken, just abused and as its the OP that said he wanted a relative source of self not mm8 then your criticism is aimed at the wrong target

Comment: @mm8 yes, Don't do it, it breaks how the DataContext works, and suggesting it results in noobs asking questions here as to why their bindings are broke af.

Comment: No, it doesn't break how DataContext *works*. It breaks the DataContext *inheritance* which I clearly described in my answer: "A child element inherits the DataContext of its parent element in the element tree unless the DataContext property is explicitly set to something else.".

Answer (score 1):

The best way to answer your question is to explain MVVM

The M is the Data Model, this controls access to data, ie links to Web Services, Databases, Files, Etc

The V is the View, its controls how data is gathered from the users and displayed to the user

The VM is the interface between the 2, it collects the data from the model that needs to be displayed to the user and processes input from the users, validating and performing business checks on data before it is saved to the model

so to answer your first question controls are view elements they collect and display data to the user, if they are doing anything else then you have broken MVVM

to answer your Second questions, if you have correctly built your control you add it in the same way as you add any other control such as a ListView or Button, how you get data into your control depends on how you built it, if that means you designed it to be bound on the datacontext then thats what you do if not then bind to the correct dependency property you set up in the controls code file

Comment: Yep, I finally got it. I didn't need another CustomControls, the ItemsControl was just fine for what I needed to do.

Comment: the power of templates can be a bit tricky to get your head round when your coming from a winforms envionment