# Multi stage databinding with a custom usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, binding

I have a custom control with a ViewModel. In this control I make programatically binding from the properties of the control to the ViewModel.

When I use the control and I make a binding to the property the value's aren't updated. I have the this for the bindings

**In the customControl ViewModel**

```
    private string _InitValue;

    public string InitValue
    {
        get { return _InitValue; }
        set { _InitValue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged();}
    }
```

**In the customControl I set the binding**

```
    initValueBinding = new Binding();
    initValueBinding.Source = LocalDataContext;
    initValueBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("InitValue");
    initValueBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;
    initValueBinding.BindsDirectlyToSource = true;
    initValueBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Default;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, PlusMinControl.InitValueProperty, initValueBinding);
```

The InitValueProperty is a dependency property.

```
    public static DependencyProperty InitValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(InitValue), typeof(string), typeof(PlusMinControl), new PropertyMetadata( new PropertyChangedCallback(test)) );
    private static void test(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ;
    }
    public string InitValue
    {
        get { return ((string)(base.GetValue(PlusMinControl.InitValueProperty))); }
        set { base.SetValue(PlusMinControl.InitValueProperty, value); }
    }
```

**For the implementation of the customControl**

```
     <plm:PlusMinControl InitValue="{Binding InitVal}" />
```

In the code behind I set the datacontext and I've InitVal defined as a normal property.

When I debug the code I can trace the changes till the PropertyChangedCallback but the property in the viewmodel isn't updated.

Can anyone tell me what I do wrong? And how I should fix this.

Thank you!

Comment: what is this `InitValue="{Binding InitVal}"`: where is `InitVal` property in the ViewModel? You show an `InitValue` in the ViewModel and it's odd that you have the same name for the dp and for the VM property... also are you doing why both xaml and code-behind binding?

Comment: The coded bindings are made in the control PlusMinControl. The xaml binding is where the PlusMinControl is implemented. InitVal is defined in the datacontext of the implementation. I hope this clarifies my structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have inverted and mixed same init :

this makes the binding property=viewmodel

```
<plm:PlusMinControl InitValue="{Binding InitVal}" />
```

and this too

```
"initValueBinding = new Binding();....."
```

this must be enough, remove the binding code

```
<plm:PlusMinControl InitialValue ="{Binding InitValue}" />
```

change the property to InitialValue in the control

Comment: I know what you mean with this. But in this case I have two different viewmodels one for the handling of my control and one for the handling of my control and one with data at the implementation. But it doesn't work to make the combination.

Comment: no, no, you have a customCtrl.xaml + customCtrl.cs => no viewmodel and any viewmodel you want to bind to it with the associated model => suggest to have a look to a sample : http://wfpbookreader.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CBR/CBR/Components/Controls/RatingControl.cs  +  http://wfpbookreader.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CBR/CBR/Resources/XAML/Controls/RatingControl.xaml and how to use it in a solution http://wfpbookreader.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer this clarifies what I did wrong for a custom control no viewmodel is used.

Comment: I searched for some more information this discusses basically the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497219/wpf-best-practices-do-custom-controls-work-well-with-the-mvvm-design

Answer (score 0):

change BindingMode.OneWayToSource to BindingMode.TwoWay

Comment: I tried to set both bindings to TwoWay and as well only the binding in the control but this makes no difference. It stops at the PropertyChangedCallback

Comment: private static void OnImageChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(d))
                return;

            PageControl element = d as PageControl;
            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                element.ManageScrool();
                element.Fit(e.NewValue as ImageSource);
            }
        }

Comment: Basically this means on the property change event you set the variable again in your viewmodel?